# Exception while running ResNet in deeplearning4j

Tags: deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I tried to run ResNet50 computation graph provided in ZooModel of deeplearning4j but got following error while calling init() method of resNet. I have 10 classes and each image is 64*64.

Please suggest the correct way of initializing.

**Code**

```
ResNet50Builder builder = ResNet50.builder();
        ResNet50 resNet = builder.numClasses(10).cacheMode(CacheMode.NONE)
                   .workspaceMode(WorkspaceMode.NONE).inputShape(new int[] {3, 64, 64}).build();
        ComputationGraph computationGraph = resNet.init();
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.deeplearning4j.exception.DL4JInvalidConfigException: Invalid configuration for layer (idx=77, name=res4a_branch2b, type=ConvolutionLayer) for height dimension:  Invalid input configuration for kernel height. Require 0 < kH <= inHeight + 2*padH; got (kH=3, inHeight=2, padH=0)
Input type = InputTypeConvolutional(h=2,w=2,c=256), kernel = [3, 3], strides = [1, 1], padding = [0, 0], layer size (output channels) = 256, convolution mode = Same
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.InputTypeUtil.getOutputTypeCnnLayers(InputTypeUtil.java:327)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.ConvolutionLayer.getOutputType(ConvolutionLayer.java:191)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.graph.LayerVertex.getOutputType(LayerVertex.java:131)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration.getLayerActivationTypes(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:536)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration.addPreProcessors(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:449)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.ComputationGraphConfiguration$GraphBuilder.build(ComputationGraphConfiguration.java:1201)
    at org.deeplearning4j.zoo.model.ResNet50.init(ResNet50.java:91)
    at org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.ResNet.run(ResNet.java:145)
    at org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.ResNet.main(ResNet.java:306)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from other forum (https://community.konduit.ai/t/error-while-running-resnet50-zoomodel-example/417)

The image is too small, which results in filters being too large after the first few constitutional layers.